# Cassandra: how to get all hosts from cluster?

Tags: java, cassandra

Are there any possibilities to get all hosts from the cassandra cluster via client API. I know that we can use the [nodetool](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/NodeTool) to ring all nodes from the console, and NodeCmd for JMX access for the same functionality, but I need just a list of hosts and ips, like ConnectionPool for [Hector Client API](https://github.com/hector-client/hector)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call the describe_ring Thrift method, or (in 1.2) `SELECT * FROM system.peers`

Comment: It maybe help me but I will check it later, because I am receiving Execption with END_OF_FILE type, from describe_ring method, will investigate this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the Java driver the information is available via [`cluster.getMetadata().getAllHosts()`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/Metadata.html#getAllHosts--).

Other drivers should have essentially the same API, following their language conventions.

Comment: Not anymore in driver 4.x